# 3rd party memory for SUN T2000

Tags: memory, sun

I am considering to use 3rd party memory for an upgrade for a T2000.
Are there any special things to consider? I have checked the memory banks and I would use the same size of chips for the upgrade? How is your general experience with non-SUN memory to be used with Sun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid Dataram if at all possible.  We've used it in some older Sun gear.  They have a lifetime warranty for a reason, it gets used quite often.

However, I try to avoid 3rd party memory at all cost (and with the price of Sun memory, it is a co$t).  When it comes time to place a service call with Sun, their first response is to remove 3rd party memory before continuing with troubleshooting.

Comment: I was thinking about http://www.compuram.de/.

Comment: I used compuram and it worked like a charme.